# Cocoa One Application using Call another Application methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am working on Cocoa mac applications i have two cocoa application like Application A and B.
i need to call methods like application A using call application B methods.its possible or not please help me.

Comment: I can't see how that's possible.  My understanding is the only way of doing anything like that would be to use a custom URL which Application B supports.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try in my application

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer here, but I have managed to do this once using using NSTask, NSPipe and NSConnection. My "second" application was a helper application, which had to be launched by the first. Looking at my code I believe…

- NSTask launched the second app, passing parameters as required
- NSConnection then opened a communications channel, and told the "second" application what port to communicate on
- NSPipe was just to collect StdErr/StdOut from the second app, in case of problems loading.

You can then read and write to the app using regular read/write calls from both sides (but to a stream instead of a file -- eg. NSInputStream and NSOutputStream).

The above is sketchy because I really can't remember the details, even while looking at my code. I guess some further documentation was in order :)

Hope this helps